# a flux:field.file without the fileupload

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x, flux

Is it possible to get a flux:field.file (for an image) without the `Chose file` button (marked yellow in the picture)? So basicly I want the user just to allow to chose files from filelists.

[image]

Comment: I guess theres no config/TS for that. I would take a look in the permission area. Maybe there is a checkbox somewhere but don't think so. There are a few other "dirty" solutions from editing the core, over load custom backend CSS to hide the field, to Javascript returning false on that input file click. - http://hatetypo3.blogspot.co.at/2008/04/welcome-to-i-hate-typo3-list.html

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no such solution. The reason lies in the way the TYPO3 Core constructs the field.